Video is not playing in android phone browser like chrome, brave in nextjs14
I am trying to play a video on the iOS and Android browsers. It works on iOS but not on Android. Here is my code:
import { serverClient } from "@/app/_trpc/serverClient";

const PublishedPage = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { collectionId: string; pageId: string };
}) => {
  const client = serverClient();

  const currentPage = await (
    await client
  ).page.get({ id: params.pageId ?? "" });
  return (
    <div className="z-40 flex w-full flex-col gap-3">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">{currentPage?.title}</h1>
      {!!currentPage?.videoUrl && (
        <>
          <video
            id={currentPage.id}
            controls
            className="w-full max-w-3xl rounded"
            playsInline
          >
            <source src={currentPage?.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </>
      )}
      <div className="prose prose-violet lg:prose-lg">
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentPage?.blocksHtml ?? "" }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PublishedPage;

I am using in Next.js 14 and it is a server component. The video is playing in every browser in iOS but in Android it doesn't work. I've tried both Brave and Chrome but I am not able to play the video. I tried to play the video using local files also but it's working on everywhere except on the Android browsers
I tried to find answers on internet but I got nothing.
How do I fix this?
